Inequalities in the Evans PDE, p.352
I am reading the Evans's PDE, p.352 ( Chapter 7.1.1. b. ) and stuck at understanding some inequalities. I think I am begginer of partial differential equation.
( Evans's book 7.1.1. a. ) Assume that $U$ is an open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and set $U_T:=U\times (0,T]$ for some fixed time $T>0$. We will first study the initial/boundary-value problem
$$ u_t+Lu=f \ \text{in} \ U_T\\
    u=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial U \times [0,T] \\ 
    u=g \ \text{on} \ U \times \{t=0\}  \tag{1} ,$$
where $f:U_T \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: U \to \mathbb{R}$ are given, and $u: \bar{U}_T \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown, $u=u(x,t).$ The letter $L$ denotes for each time $t$ a second-order partial differential operator, having the divergence form
$$ Lu=- \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(a^{ij}(x,t)u_{x_i})_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b^{i}(x,t)u_{x_i} + c(x,t)u \tag{2} $$
( Evans's book 7.1.1. b. ) We assume now that
$$ a^{ij},b^{i},c \in L^{\infty}(U_T) \ (i,j=1, \dots,n), \tag{5}$$
$$ f \in L^2(U_T), \tag{6}$$
$$ g\in L^{2}(U). \tag{7}$$
We will also always suppose $a^{ij}=a^{ji}$ ( $i,j=1,\dots,n$ ).
Let us now define, by analogy with the notation introduced in Chapter $6$, the time-dependent bilinear form
$$ B[u,v;t]:=\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a^{ij}(\cdot, t)u_{x_i}v_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b^{i}(\cdot, t)u_{x_i}v + c(\cdot, t)uv dx \tag{8} $$
for $u,v\in H^{1}_{0}(U)$ and a.e. $0 \le t \le T$.
Then, Evans argues as follows :


Why each inequalities are true? Here $H^{-1}(U)$ is the dual space to $H^{1}_{0}(U)$.
Q.1. For the first inequality, I am trying to use the next theorem ( Theorem 1 in Chap. 5.9.1. in the Evans's book ). We will write $\langle \ , \rangle$ to denote the pairing between $H^{-1}(U)$ and $H^{1}_{0}(U)$.

THEOREM 1 ( Characterization of $H^{-1}$ ).

(i) Assume $f\in H^{-1}(U)$. Then there exist functions $f^{0},f^{1},\dots,f^{n}$ in $L^{2}(U)$ such that
$$\tag{1} \langle f,v \rangle = \int_U f^{0}v + \sum_{i=1}^{n} f^{i}v_{x_i} dx \ (v\in H^{1}_{0}(U)). $$
(ii) Furthermore,
$$ ||f||_{H^{-1}(U)}=\inf \{ (\int_{U} \sum_{i=0}^{n} | f^{i}|^2 dx)^{1/2} | f \ \text{satisfies (1) for } f^{0},\dots, f^{n} \in L^{2}(U) \}. $$


Usage of this theorem may works? Note that in $(10)$ in the picture, $u_t = g^{0} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}g^{j}_{x_j}$. Perhaps, for each $v\in H^{1}_{0}(U)$, $ \langle u_t, v \rangle = \int_U g^{0} v + \sum_{i=1}^{n} g^{i}v_{x_i} dx $ ? Then we may use the Theorem 1.. We may use the integration by parts formula? If so, how?
Q.2. I don't know how can we derive the second inequality at all. Should we use some deep theorem?
Can anyone ( possibly expert ) explain these inequalites more friendly?

Your understanding of question 1 is correct, but you should be aware that there's an identifications that's implicitly being made. Indeed, we have $$ u_t = g_0 +\sum_{j=1}^ng^j_{x_j},$$ so for all $v\in H^1_0(U)$ then integration by parts gives \begin{align}
(u_t,v)_{L^2(U)}&=\int_U vg_0\,dx +\sum_{j=1}^n\int_U v g^j_{x_j} \, dx \\
&=\int_U vg_0\,dx -\sum_{j=1}^n\int_U  g^j v _{x_j} \, dx . \tag{$\ast$} 
\end{align} Note $(\cdot,\cdot)_{L^2(U)}$ is the inner product in $L^2(U)$ (I'm not confusing it with $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$). Now, when Evans says that $u_t\in H^{-1}(U)$ he is identifying $u_t$ with the functional $F$ defined by $\langle F , v \rangle := (u_t,v)_{L^2(U)}$. Hence, with this identification, $$ \| u_t\|_{H^{-1}(U)}=\inf \bigg \{\bigg ( \sum_{j=0}^n \| f^j\|_{L^2(U)}^2 \bigg)^{\frac12} \text{ s.t. } u_t \text{ satisfies }(1)\text{ for } f^0,\dots,f^n \in L^2(U)\bigg \} \leq \bigg ( \sum_{j=0}^n \| g^j\|_{L^2(U)}^2 \bigg)^{\frac12}$$ since $(\ast)$ implies that $f^0=g^0$, $f^j=-g^j$ $j=1,\dots,n$ satisfies $(1)$ and each $g^j\in L^2(U)$ since $a^{ij},b^i,c\in L^\infty(U)$ and $u$ is smooth.
For the second inequality, we have $$ g^0 = f- \sum_{j=1}^nb^j u_{x_j} -cu,$$ so \begin{align*}
\| g^0\|_{L^2(U)} &\leq \| f\|_{L^2(U)}+\sum_{j=1}^n\| b^j u_{x_j}\|_{L^2(U)}+\|cu\|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\leq \| f\|_{L^2(U)}+\sum_{j=1}^n\| b^j\|_{L^\infty(U)} \|u_{x_j}\|_{L^2(U)}+\|c\|_{L^\infty(U)}\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\\
&\leq \| f\|_{L^2(U)}+\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n\| b^j\|_{L^\infty(U)} +\|c\|_{L^\infty(U)}\bigg) \|u\|_{H^1(U)}.
\end{align*} Similary, for $j=1,\dots,n$, $$ g^j=\sum_{i=1}^na^{ij}u_{x_i},$$ so \begin{align*}
\| g^j\|_{L^2(U)} &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\| a^{ij}u_{x_i}\|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\leq  \sum_{i=1}^n\| a^{ij}\|_{L^\infty(U) }\|u_{x_i}\|_{L^2(U)}\\
&\leq \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^n\| a^{ij}\|_{L^\infty(U) } \bigg ) \|u\|_{H^1(U)}.
\end{align*} Hence, \begin{align*}
\bigg ( \sum_{i=0}^n \| g^i\|_{L^2(U)}^2 \bigg )^{\frac 12} &\leq \sum_{i=0}^n \| g^i\|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\leq \| f\|_{L^2(U)}+\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n\| b^j\|_{L^\infty(U)} +\|c\|_{L^\infty(U)}\bigg) \|u\|_{H^1(U)} \\
&\qquad + \bigg (\sum_{i,j=1}^n\| a^{ij}\|_{L^\infty(U) } \bigg ) \|u\|_{H^1(U)} \\
&= \| f\|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\qquad +\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n\| b^j\|_{L^\infty(U)} +\|c\|_{L^\infty(U)}+\sum_{i,j=1}^n\| a^{ij}\|_{L^\infty(U) }\bigg) \|u\|_{H^1(U)}  
\end{align*}

Thank you very much ! Soft questions : 1) for the first question ( about the first inequality ), to use the integration by parts formula ( Evans's book p.628 Theorem 2 ), for each $j=1,2, \dots, n$, $g^j := \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{ij}u_{x_i} $ should be in $C^{1}(\bar{U})$. How can we prove this? 2) In deduction $(*)$, the surface integral term $\int_{\partial U}g^{j} v \nu^{j} dS$ vanishes since $u=0$ on $\partial U \times [0, T]$? 3) bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has finte measure ( w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure ) ? Then $a^{ij}, b^{i},c \in L^{\infty}(U) \subseteq L^{2}(U)$.

And multiplication of $L^2(U)$-element and smooth function is also contained in $L^{2}(U)$? Then I think we can convince by construction that $g^{j}\in L^{2}(U)$ for all $j=0,\dots ,n$ . 4) Finally, it seems that by definition the domain of functions $g^{j}$ ( $j=0,1, \dots ,n$ ) is $U_T:=U \times (0,T]$, not $U$. Then, what the statement $g^{j} \in L^{2}(U)$ means?

For 1), you're right this is an issue in theory since $a^{ij}$ is only $L^\infty$ not $C^1$, but it's missing the point. Evans isn't presenting a rigorous proof at this stage - he is just motivating what we should expect to see. So, even though I don't think he explicitly says it, he is probably thinking of all the coefficients being smooth

For 2), $v$ doesn't depend on time, but yes $\int_{\partial U} g^j v \nu^j=0$ since $v$ 'vanishes on $\partial U$ since $v\in H^1_0(U)$. For 3), yes. For the multiplication question, it depends on if the function is smooth in $U$ or the closure of $U$ - in the first case no (for example, $1/x$ is smooth in $(0,1)$, but not in $L^2((0,1))$ and yes for the second case because it is bounded by the extreme value theorem. Again, Evan's is probably thinking of everything as being as nice as possible, so assume he means smooth in the closure of $U$

For 4), the inequality is for each $t\in (0,T]$, so it means that the functions $x\mapsto g^j(x,t)$ is in $L^2(U)$ for each $t$

Thanks for kind explanation. Final question : For $(2)$, why $v |_{\partial U} =0$? An issue that confusing me is that the domain of $v\in H^{1}0(U)$ is $U$, and may not be defined on $\partial U$. We may use the Theorem 5.5.1 - (i) ( Trace Theorem ) in the Evans's book p.258 and Theorem 5.5.2 ( Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$ ). But to use the Theorem 5.5.1-(i) ( so that $Tv= v|{\partial U}$ ) , $\partial U$ should be $C^{1}$ ( In our question Evans don't mention that $\partial U$ is $C^{1}$ ) and $v\in W^{1,2}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$. And $v$ may not be in $C(\bar{U})$.

But alternatively, note that $\int_{\partial U } g^{j} v \nu^j := \int_{\partial U} \sum_{i=1}^na^{ij}u_{x_i} v \nu^j dS$. Since $u=0$ on $\partial U \times [0,T]$, the integral is zero.. Am I misunderstanding something?
P.s. And for your final estimate in your edited answer, why the $n ||c||{L^{\infty}(U)}$ appears? Just $||c||{L^{\infty}(U)}$ is correct? I think it is typo.
